# Navigating to the same route with different parameters

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I navigate in the typescript file with

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`account-transactions/${code}`);
```

however, my active route is

```
http://localhost:4200/account-transactions/10102
```

but if try to navigate to, say:

```
http://localhost:4200/account-transactions/99999
```

the url address changes, but the component is not reloaded

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using snapshot to get your value, so in order to work you need to user Activated Route so you can subscribe to detect changes in your routing
You should change your init code for the following:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = params['id']; //or whatever you put in your routing
       // here your logic to use this id

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `this.router.navigateByUrl(`../account-transactions/${code}`);`

or if you are using routerLink

`routerLink="../account-transactions/' + code"` or
`[routerLink]="['../account-transactions', code]"`

Comment: Have you tested the code before suggesting? Mine didn't solve the problem...

Comment: @Swastik yes at that time...this was in 2019 if this suggestion doesn't work for you then it could be a version issue...or who knows maybe you're not implementing it right...anyway good luck

Comment: okay Thanks! I implemented this differently, though that causes full page reload. If you have any other suggestions based on current version you can share.

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not reload the component when the URL parameters change. You can instead subscribe to the Observables present in `ActivatedRoute` interface (https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) in the component you wish to reload.

In your component

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

...

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
            // Do something on URL parameter change
            this.loadAccountTransactions(routeParams.code);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also the accepted answer, but @JpCrow answered first. Thank you so much anyway!